# Logging into Outlook using powershell with no user logged on

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, automation, scheduled-tasks

I was wondering if its possible to create a powershell script to log into a specific outlook mail box and than add the script to the scheduled task so that no user has to be logged on.

Comment: Do you mean log to a predefined profile? Or open other user's Exchange mailbox?

Comment: Open another user's Exchange mailbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to open an arbitrary Exchange mailbox, you can either

1. Use Outlook Object Model (which cannot be used in a service, such as the Scheduler) to log to a predefined profile (Namespace.Logon) and call `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`. If the set of mailboxes is always the same, you can add these static mailboxes to the profile (open them as delegate mailboxes) and access them programmatically using the `Namespace.Stores` collection. Again, Outlook should not be used in a service/scheduler.
2. [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) - it is HTTP based, so you can use it from a service
3. [Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) - just like EWS, it is HTTP based, so you can use it from a service
4. [Extended MAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424(v=office.15).aspx) (C++ or Delphi only). native API used by Outlook itself. It can be used in a service.
5. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - it wraps Extended MAPI and can be used in any language from a service). It lets you dynamically log to an Exchange mailbox using [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonExchangeMailbox` / `LogonExchangeHostedMailbox` (no existing profile required). Other mailboxes can be opened using `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox`.

Comment: I new to powershell, how would I go about doing your first suggestion

Comment: I know next to nothing about PowerShell, but you can start at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can log on to a specific user profile programmatically. The [Logon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class logs the user on to MAPI, obtaining a MAPI session.

*Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.*

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Instead, you may consider using a low level API on which Outlook is built - Extended MAPI. Or use any third-party wrappers around that API.